# Echoing div tag with style tags in php to display progress bar

Tags: php, css

I am trying to display a progress bar using div tag and the width%.

The code looks like this:

```
$width = $density;
$width = sprintf ("%d\n",$width);

echo '<div style="width:200px;height:15px;background:#FFFFFF;border:1px     
solid #000000;">'; // displays the outer white bar

echo '<div style="width: $width%; height:15px;background:#0033FF;font-size:8px;line-height:8px;">'; // displays the colored bar according to the value of width

echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Problem: the code is not taking the variable $width in the second echo.

It simply displays either a 0% figure (blank bar, even when the $width is 100), or a full colored bar when the value of $width is 0. (I echoed the values to cross check with the bar display)

When I give it a hard figure in percentage, the bar works and shows that much % in colored area.

I have searched for a fix and tried various combinations, such as using:

```
echo '<div style="width: '. $width. ' %; [rest of tags here]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a special way to pass a variable in a style tag along with the % symbol?

Comment: Remove the `\n` from `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a problem with the `sprintf` call. Either way, I would probably write it like this (tested):

```
$width = intval($density);
```

Then you can use your same code:

```
echo '<div style="width: $width%; height:15px;background:#0033FF;font-size:8px;line-height:8px;">';
```